# Query working in 2.2 but not in 2.3.3

Tags: android, sms

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

// returns all the results from the given Context 
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);

if ( c == null || 0 == c.getCount() )
{
    Log.i("CHANDRA","Err --> No message in Inbox ********* ##########");
    return;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? How does your logcat, error messages look?

Answer (score 1):

There's no official way to handle sms-es. `SMS_CONTENT_URI` could change depending on the OEM. There's no guarantee you will have `"content://sms/inbox"` on different brand of phones (although it's quite likely you will have this URI, because most of the phones are using the default Android SMS manager).